# How to display only the directories from s3 bucket using aws cli command

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, devops, aws-cli

I need to display all the directories present inside the s3 bucket, where some directories are hidden and are shown again only if I filter the version to 'show' instead of hide.

The same things goes to files where inside the directory we cant see the file but when we chose the filter in version to 'show', it shows the files.

How can we see these files and directories in aws-cli. Please do help if you have a solution.

---

For example:

```
roxor@ubuntu:~$ aws s3 ls s3://dw-etl-source-prod
workday dsr
```

I need to get 4 directories, but since the directories contains versioning it is not been shown. If i filter in version to show it gives all the files in aws s3 UI, but how I can do the same using AWS CLI.

Comment: Could you clarify or/and show some expected result?

Comment: roxor@ubuntu:~$ aws s3 ls s3://dw-etl-source-prod \n
workday
dsr \n 

i need to get 4 directories but since the directories contains versioning it is not been shown. If i filter in version to show it gives all the files in aws s3 UI but how will i do the same in aws cli

Comment: There are no directories in S3, only buckets and files. "directory1/directory2/file" is just a name of the file in a bucket. "directory3/directory4/file" is another file in the same bucket - it stored close to the previous file.

Answer (score 7):

If you are on a POSIX based system and want to use the familiar `aws s3 ls` syntax, try:

```
aws s3 ls --recursive <s3Uri> | cut -c32- | xargs -d '\n' -n 1 dirname | uniq
```

Here's a quick explanation. As of Nov 2020, `aws s3 ls` prints objects in the following format:

```
<date> <time> <size> <path>
```

The idea is to extract `<path>` from this listing using `cut`, pass it to `dirname` to extract the directory name, and finally use `uniq` to avoid repeats. `cut -c32-` trims the s3 listing up to the 31st character. You might have to adjust this if your file sizes are too large.

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't just pull out the 4th field instead of the cutting an explicit number of characters? `awk` or a different call to `cut` seem like they'd be more robust.

Comment: @MichaelAlbers Unfortunately `aws s3 ls` uses spaces instead of tab characters as delimiters, so extracting the _4th field_ wasn't so easy to me. Trimming 31 characters was the best I could do.

Answer (score 2):

My Solution:

```sh
aws s3 ls://<your bucket>/<path>/<to>/ | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I combined a few of these solutions into a simple one liner that works by checking for anything in the directory (but not recursively) that is also a directory (anything with a filename ending in /)

`aws s3 ls s3://<your bucket>/<path>/<to>/ | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F '/' '/\// {print $1}'`

Hop this helps!

Answer (score 1):

first, on the OPs question, i don't think the `aws s3 ls` can show the versioned objects. The only way i know of is using something like

```
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket  <bucket-name> [--output text|json]
```

if using json output, you could use some `jq` hacking to get the output you want.

but as many come here from search engines, searching for a way to show recursivelly the objects of s3 that en

for the MacOS users out there or if you don't want to use 'tr ...|xargs -0'

@nikhiwee's solution didn't work for me (`xargs -d`  doesn't exist on MacOS without installing gnu versions), so came up with an option using only awk + sort

As of Oct/2023 `aws s3 ls --recursive <s3Uri>` still output's:

```
<date> <time> <size> <object-name>
```

so the solution that worked for me

```
aws s3 ls --recursive <s3Uri> | awk '{ sub( /\/.[^\/]*$/,"/",$4 ); print $4}' | sort -u
```

Answer (score 1):

hard to tell from the OP if the question wants the `--recusive` entire list of directories or just the top level directories.

Based on those `awk` answers that extract the second column, you can grep the  lines with "PRE" in the current output from `aws s3 ls` to get just the directories with, eg.:

```
aws s3 ls s3://<bucket-name>/ | grep PRE | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it.

```
aws s3 ls s3://<bucket-name> --recursive --human-readable --summarize | awk '{print $5}' | awk -F '/' '/\// {print $1}' | sort -u
```